# How to filter the app-jobs-list , based on the events like when an user add or removes an option from filter in angular?

Tags: angular, observable

[components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNQPg.png)

I am new to angular and trying to build this app as seen in image.
The app is a challenge from frontendmentor.io

The components are app-filter, app-jobs-list and app-job.
Basically, the user can add an option to the filter or remove an option from the filter and the jobs should be shown accordingly.
I have a service called jobsService, to get the jobs from an API like this:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class JobsService {
  jobsUrl = 'api/jobs';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getJobs() {
    return this.http.get(this.jobsUrl);
  }
}
```

and here is the jobs-list component

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-jobs-list',
  templateUrl: './jobs-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./jobs-list.component.css'],
})
export class JobsListComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private jobsService: JobsService) {}
  @Input() viewLayout: any;
  jobs = [];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.jobsService.getJobs().subscribe({
      next: (res: any) => {
        this.jobs = res;
      },
    });
  }
}
```

So, the jobs-list component has the list of jobs.
I am using ngFor directive to render the list of jobs and pass data to app-job component.
The user can add an option or tag to filter, the options are in job component, and can also delete an option or tag from filter, and the jobs-list should be filtered and shown to the user accordingly.

How do I achieve this functionality?

Any feedback is welcome

Comment: You need two variables:`jobs` and `filteredJobs`. you loop over "filteredJobs" and you change "filteredJobs" when you "click" one or another options. NOTE: it's impossible help you more whithout know about the structure of your data

Comment: @Eliseo what iam trying to achieve is Filter a list of components based on events(like button click) happening in another component i.e no parent child relationship between components.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is think in variables. In the first moment you has not worry about components.

Imagine your data is like

```
[
{title:"Senior Frontend Developer",date:"2022-04-11",...,tags:"FrontEnd,Css"},
{title:"Junior Frontend Developer",date:"2022-04-11",...,tags:"Html,Css"},
...
]
```

You first create an array with the different "tags". Use a function

```
getTags(data)
{
  const tags=data.reduce((a,b)=>[...a,...b.tags.split(",")],[])
   return tags.filter((x,index)=>tags.indexOf(x)==index)
              .map(x=>({label:x,selected:true}))
}
```

Now we are ready to filter the data, so make a function to return a filtered jobs based in "this.jobs" and an array with the selected tags

```
getFilteredJobs(tagsSelected)
{
   return this.jobs.filter(x=>{
      let included:boolean=false;
      const jobTags=x.tags.split(",")
      tagsSelected.forEach(tag=>{
          included=included || jobTags.indexOf(tag)>=0
      })
      return included
   })
}
```

Now  we can have a "primer outline"

```
<label *ngFor="let tag of tags">
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    [ngModel]="tag.selected"
    (ngModelChange)="tag.selected = $event; onChange()"
  />
  {{ tag.label }}
</label>
<pre>
  {{ jobsFiltered | json }}
</pre>
```

And our function onChange()

```
onChange()
{
  const tagsSelected=this.tags.filter(x=>x.selected).map(x=>x.label)
  this.jobsFiltered=this.getFilteredJobs(tagsSelected)

}
```

Well, we are going to improve our app. First we are going to make a component to filter. See that we need as `Input` the tags, and we use a `Output` with the tags selected.

Some like

```
<label *ngFor="let tag of tags">
<input
  type="checkbox"
  [ngModel]="tag.selected"
  (ngModelChange)="tag.selected = $event; onChange()"
/>
{{ tag.label }}
</label>

  @Input() tags
  @Output() filterChange:EventEmitter<string[]>=new EventEmitter<string[]>()
  constructor() { }

  onChange()
  {
    const tagsSelected=this.tags.filter(x=>x.selected).map(x=>x.label)
    this.filterChange.emit(tagsSelected)

  }
```

And we create another component "job" to show the job

```
<h1>{{job.title}}</h1>
{{job.date}}

  @Input() job:any
  constructor() { }
```

Now our component can be like

```
<app-filter [tags]="tags" 
   (filterChange)="jobsFiltered=getFilteredJobs($event)">
</app-filter>
<app-job *ngFor="let job of jobsFiltered" [job]="job"></app-job>
```

See that the functions getTags,getFilteredJobs, and the variables jobs and filteredJobs remain in our main.component

See the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2sh4n2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

NOTE: Well, the "hard work" is beauty the JobComponents and the FilterComponent by some that make use of "Chips". but we have now the "basic"

NOTE2: I imagine one possible solution. You can think about another. e.g. you can choose to have a JobsComponent that received as `Input` the filtered Jobs in stead of a JobComponent to show an unique Job, or you can choose that the jobsService has a function that received the "selectedTags" and give you the jobs yet filtered. There are many approach and the choose of one or another is related by the size of the dbs, and the data you has. But the important is always think **first** in the data and the variables, after think about components